# PhoneGap "On menu press launch url"

Tags: java, jquery, android, mobile, cordova

I am currently working on an e-book for the android platform. I'm using Eclipse, Dreamweaver and the phonegap libraries. Is there a way i can have a new page or dialog display on the action of pressing the menu key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your onLoad handler

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener('menubutton', onMenuKeyDown);
    }

function onMenuKeyDown() {
}
```

You can then perform any action you like in your onMenuKeyDown function.